# Find several files with one command in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I would like to know Emacs' equivalent of Vim's :n, which opens several files according to a glob.

Say I have this directory:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pablo pablo   31 Jun 25 00:59 /home/pablo/tmp/prueba.php  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pablo pablo 2442 May  9  1913 /home/pablo/tmp/sin_soap.php  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pablo pablo  726 Jun 25 15:20 /home/pablo/tmp/verificar.php
```

If I wanted to open all those files, I could type the following in Vim:

```
:n *php
```

That will give me one buffer for every file; I don't know how to do that in Emacs (when it's already open, of course I can do `emacs *php` in a shell).

I'm happy with a function that I can call from any buffer via M-x, but if there's a command that I can call in dired-mode (say, edit all marked files or something), that would be beyond cool.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110118/in-emacs-dired-how-to-find-visit-multiple-files) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the regular find-file does accept wildcards, but I was using ido-find-file. Go figure